# get only the value...not what your grepping for

Tags: unix, grep

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data output | grep NumberOfPages:
```

gives me:

```
NumberOfPages: 5
```

I don't want it to output NumberOfPages. I want to get in this case just 5. Is there a flag I can say in grep to get just that? I did a man grep and nothing seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think grep doesn't know about how to parse strings in different formats. But other utilities like `awk` will help you:

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data output | grep NumberOfPages: | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data output | grep NumberOfPages: | sed 's\NumberOfPages:\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in GNU Grep you can use the `-o` operator to get "only" the matching portion of your expression. So something like;

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data output | grep -o ' .*'
```

Could work for you. As other answers have pointed out, if you want only the number you'd be better off using something in addition to `grep`.

For example:

```
$ echo 'NumberOfPages: 5' | grep -o ' .*'
 5
```

Notice the space before the 5 being included.

Comment: `.*` matches to any number of any symbols.